# How to delete dynamic added nodes

Tags: java, javafx

I generate four `HBox`es in a for loop. Every `HBox` has 1 "delete button". How can I target the one delete button to delete the corresponding `HBox` only? I add all `HBox`es to a `VBox` called `questionField`.

Right now I'm using:

```
private void removeAnswer() {
    this.questionField.getChildren().removeAll(hBox);
}
```

But that deletes all 4 `HBox`es. I need something to be able to target the specific `HBox` alone.

This is the loop:

```
newAnswerTextField = new TextField[4];
answerCheckbox = new CheckBox[4];
ToggleGroup answerToggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
radioButtonAnswer = new RadioButton[4];
hBox = new HBox[4];

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    hBox[i] = new HBox();
    Button deleteButton = new Button("X");
    deleteButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        removeAnswer();
    });

    newAnswerTextField[i] = new TextField();
    newAnswerTextField[i].setText("Fråga " + questionNumber + " svar " + answerNumber++);
    hBox[i].getChildren().addAll(deleteButton, newAnswerTextField[i]);

    radioButtonAnswer[i] = new RadioButton("Rätt svar");
    radioButtonAnswer[i].setToggleGroup(answerToggleGroup);
    hBox[i].getChildren().add(radioButtonAnswer[i]);

    questionField.getChildren().add(hBox[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply pass the `HBox` to remove as parameter to your `removeAnswer` method:

```
private void removeAnswer(Node answer) {
    this.questionField.getChildren().remove(answer);
}
```

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    final HBox answer = new HBox();
    hBox[i] = answer;
    Button deleteButton = new Button("X");
    deleteButton.setOnAction(e -> {
       removeAnswer(answer);
    });

    ...
}
```